# Reindex from bash: The encoded file ... is not permissioned for this server

Tags: reindex, shell, ioncube

From a bash script I run reindex:

```
php -f shell/indexer.php reindexall;
```

and get this error `The encoded file ... is not permissioned for this server`. Reindexing from web interface works fine.

Looks like the file is protected with ioncube.

Anyway I can still reindex from bash?

Comment: there are silly mistake in you code -- missing on shell command php  -f shell/indexer.php --reindexall

Comment: See at http://www.branded3.com/blogs/re-indexing-magento-command-line/

Comment: @AmitBera Thanks, but simple `reindexall` does work. It is listed in `indexer.php help`. Works fine for all indices but two throw this error because of one extension. I contacted the manufacture how he can change that...

Comment: I found an [ionCube post](http://forum.ioncube.com/viewtopic.php?p=4583&sid=b48ca3289c5bf268efc949d9463ec085#4583) about this. Looks like you can change the licence...

Comment: Dear I have no idea regarding on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks you may use custom extension code which is encoded by ionCube with `--allowed-server` option set to your domain name.

You may contact extension developer and ask for files encoded with `--allowed-server` option set to IP, not to domain name or even better ask for open source code.